# macport export fails with "Failed to create dir"

Tags: export, port

I have been updated to Mavericks and installing many stuffs through port but stuck. Heres what I got:

```
afsar@Afsars-MacBook-Pro:~# port extract xmlindent
...................................................
--->  Extracting xmlindent
Error: org.macports.extract for port xmlindent returned: command execution failed
Please see the log file for port xmlindent for details:
   /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_Volumes_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_textproc_xmlindent/xmlindent/main.log
To report a bug, follow the instructions in the guide:
http://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets
Error: Processing of port xmlindent failed
```

I looked within the log file and found:

```
:info:extract --->  Extracting xmlindent-0.2.17.tar.gz
:debug:extract setting option extract.args to '/opt/local/var/macports/distfiles/xmlindent/xmlindent-0.2.17.tar.gz'
:debug:extract Environment: CPATH='/opt/local/include' CC_PRINT_OPTIONS_FILE='/opt/local/var/macports/build/_Volumes_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_textproc_xmlindent/xmlindent/work/.CC_PRINT_OPTIONS' LIBRARY_PATH='/opt/local/lib' CC_PRINT_OPTIONS='YES' MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET='10.9'
:debug:extract Assembled command: 'cd "/opt/local/var/macports/build/_Volumes_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_textproc_xmlindent/xmlindent/work" && /usr/bin/gzip -dc '/opt/local/var/macports/distfiles/xmlindent/xmlindent-0.2.17.tar.gz' | /usr/bin/tar -xf -'
:debug:extract Executing command line:  cd "/opt/local/var/macports/build/_Volumes_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_textproc_xmlindent/xmlindent/work" && /usr/bin/gzip -dc '/opt/local/var/macports/distfiles/xmlindent/xmlindent-0.2.17.tar.gz' | /usr/bin/tar -xf -
:info:extract xmlindent-0.2.17/: Can't create 'xmlindent-0.2.17'
:info:extract xmlindent-0.2.17/BUGS: Failed to create dir 'xmlindent-0.2.17'Can't create 'xmlindent-0.2.17/BUGS'
:info:extract xmlindent-0.2.17/ChangeLog: Failed to create dir 'xmlindent-0.2.17'Can't create 'xmlindent-0.2.17/ChangeLog'
.....................................................................
```

It is saying **Failed to create dir** and I thought it was a permission problem and updated the variable `macportsuer` = `root` within `/opt/local/etc/macports/macports.conf` but no luck :(

I searched net for more hints. It seems it is a problem related to `tclsh` but naah; my `tclsh` was latest (8.5)

Then I guessed its an extracting issue. `tar` is failing. It might be the uid, gid (assigned to the tarred file) are non-existent in my system. So, gave a try editing `/opt/local/share/macports/Tcl/port1.0/portextract.tcl` to use `tar -xpof` rather than `tar -xf` (`po` will tell tar to assign my port's uid and gid) and no luck again :(

=====================

After more troubleshooting, I got the problem fixed. I have a little bit different case:

- I created a partition for `opt` (mounts in `/Volumes/opt`) and `/opt` was a symbolic link to `/Volumes/opt`

I updated all paths of `/opt/local/etc/macports/macports.conf` to use `/Volumes/opt` and the problem was fixed. I think the IO handling of `tclsh` does not support symbolic link traversal.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have got the problem fixed and updated the bottom of the description of the question.